# create a json out of a list of lists with many level os nesting

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings containing elements separated by dots and each element to the right is a child of the element to the left. For instance: (element0.element1.element2) element2 is a child of element1 which is a child of element0 (element0 (element1 (element2))). But the number of childs may change and I want a way to join the childs so in the end there will be a nested structure somewhat like a tree.

I can convert the list of string to a list like this:

```
[0, [1, [0]]]
[0, [1, [1]]]
[0, [2, [0]]]
[0, [3]]
[1, [0]]
```

Or a dictionary like this:

```
{0, {1, {0}}}
{0, {1, {1}}}
{0, {2, {0}}}
{0, {3}}
{1, {0}}
```

I need something like this:

```
{
"0": {
    "1": {"0", "1"},
    "2": {"0"},
    "3": {}
    },
"1": {"0"}
}
```

Simply using d.update() for every element of the list doesn't work since the next element may overwrite the current. Using d[elem0] = elem1 doesn't work because I can't initialize all the parents first to add the childs later.

Comment: Have you tried using the `json` library and simply (1) create a dict, and (2) do `json.dumps(the_dict)`?

Comment: Your output is not a valid json. Please fix it to conform to json syntax.

Comment: Please, include what you have tried so far.

Comment: @amedina I added what I tried so far at the end of the question

Comment: @Yossi it does not need to be necessarily a json file

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I can't simply create a dict. What would be the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered by [u/timbledum](https://www.reddit.com/user/timbledum) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ax0j71/ask_anything_monday_weekly_thread/ei43sqh/):

> Your output example is not possible, as you cannot have keys without
>   values. However, if you just put None as a placeholder, you can do
>   something like this (I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but
>   this works):
>
> ```
> >>> data = [
> ... '0.1.0',
> ... '0.1.1',
> ... '0.2.0',
> ... '0.3',
> ... '1.0',
> ... ]
> >>> data_split = [row.split(".") for row in data]
> >>> data_split
> [['0', '1', '0'], ['0', '1', '1'], ['0', '2', '0'], ['0', '3'], ['1', '0']]
> >>> output = {}
> >>> for row in data_split:
> ...     current_dict = output
> ...     keys = row[:-1]
> ...     value = row[-1]
> ...     for key in keys:
> ...         if key not in current_dict:
> ...             current_dict[key] = {}
> ...         current_dict = current_dict[key] 
> ...     current_dict[value] = None
> ...     
> >>> pprint(output, width=2)
> {'0': {'1': {'0': None,
>             '1': None},
>     '2': {'0': None},
>     '3': None},
> '1': {'0': None}}
> ```